# Mysql TLS version used does not meet minimal requirements for this server

Tags: openssl

I have a really old distro (debian Stretch) where from I am trying to connect to a mysql database.
The remote database has TLS1.2 configured.
when I try to connect from my debian box, mysql complains about:

> TLS version used does not meet minimal requirements for this server.

Openssl version supports TLS1.2:

> openssl version
> OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019

and also mysql version:

> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.45-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Any idea how could I force to use TLS1.2? I couldn't find any solution so far.

I already tried different solutions like setting openssl min version to TLS1.2

Comment: Just one note: you are using mariadb and not mysql. Contrary to common belief, these two are different products as they forked over a decade ago.